# Rails app : What is the best way to add default datas to production application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a Rails 6 application used in production.
When I upgrade my app, I add migrations for new tables and/or columns.

What is the best way if I have to add new default datas ?

I use seed file for initial datas, but is there something like migrations (incremental) to add datas ? I know I can add datas in migrations but I would prefer another place for that.

**[EDIT]**
Do someone know this gem : https://github.com/ilyakatz/data-migrate ?
It seems to do what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone is looking for a simple solution, data_migrate does exactly what I wanted.

https://github.com/ilyakatz/data-migrate

Data migrations are stored in db/data.
Data migrations are included in schema migration workflow with simple commands as :

```
rails db:migrate:with_data
```

If you can read spanish, this is an interesting documentation on data_migrate : https://la-guia.platan.us/stack/ruby/rails/data_migrate

When it is possible, you should avoid using ActiveRecord models in data migrations. Models are subject to change and if, for example, you have added validations it is possible that your data migrations will not pass.

This is well explained here : https://medium.com/@jeffcoh23/why-you-should-avoid-activerecord-when-using-ruby-on-rails-data-migrate-gem-2651739395d9

A good solution is to call a model created just for data migration :

```
class AddVisitorRoleToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  class MigrationUser < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = :users
  end
  
  def up
    MigrationUser.all.each do |user|
      user.update!(role: 'visitor')
      # This will NOT call User model validations
    end
  end

  def down
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In some projects we use to put data updates into `db/data-updates/<UTC TimeStamp>_add_thing.rb`. We created an own generator for those, called by `rails generate data_update AddThing` to create a migration calling / executing the contents from the corresponding update file.

Based on that you can put those default datas into `db/default-data` with similar logic for your new defaults.

You don't need to call them by mirgrations, you also may run them as `rails runner db/default-data/123_xyz.rb` in your differnt environments.

But if the new defaults are mandatory for your busines logic you should keep them as close as possible to the inventing migration!

Comment: thank you for sharing your experience. I would like to find a solution more "automatic" like migrations (one command to run all new data's update).

Comment: The data-migrate gem you added to your question does nearly same I described what we do in some projects. The gem provides much more logic than we implemented and sounds like a good solution for your question.